# Office365 OutlookServices 2.0 Read mailboxsettings

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps, outlook-restapi

My app has Mailboxsettings.ReadWrite permissions from user but I am getting the following error when trying to read mailboxsettings

```
   "code":"ErrorAccessDenied",
   "message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
```

Here is the calling code

```
var task = ServicesClient.Context.CreateQuery<string>("me/mailboxSettings"); 

var searchUri = new Uri(task.RequestUri.OriginalString);
var settings = ServicesClient.Context.Execute<string>(searchUri, "GET").SingleOrDefault();
```

In fiddler i can see the end point 
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailboxSettings

Comment: getting the same error with 
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{Id | UserPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings

Comment: Do you have the permissions selected for the Exchange API or for Microsoft Graph? If you have the permissions set up for Microsoft Graph, you need to make sure to access the API through the Microsoft Graph endpoint "https://graph.microsoft.com".

Comment: After adding MailboxSettings.readwrite permission. I can see the response  in fiddler but in code I am getting an exception "The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom or JSON element or belongs to 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data' namespace." I guess mailboxsettings doesnt work with v2.0

Comment: OutlookServices 2.0 currently doesn't support mailbox settings. I ended up using Restapi and making a web request